# Does an RDD need to be cached if used more than once?

Tags: python, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

Let's say, we have the following code.

```
x = sc.textFile(...)
y = x.map(...)
z = x.map(...)
```

Is it essential to cache `x` here? Would not caching `x` make spark read the input file twice?

Comment: No it's not essential. But your application will run faster if the RDD is cached. If it is not cached the data will be read from the filesystem twice, in your example.

Answer (score 7):

It is not necessary that these thing will make Spark to read the input twice.

Listing out all possible scenario:

**Example 1:** Files not read even once

```
x = sc.textFile(...)    #creation of RDD
y = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
z = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
```

In this case it will not do anything as there is no action along with the transformation.

**Example 2:** Files read once

```
x = sc.textFile(...)    #creation of RDD
y = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
z = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
println(y.count())    #Action of RDD
```

Only once the file will be read for y to make it map

**Example 3:** Files read twice

```
x = sc.textFile(...)    #creation of RDD
y = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
z = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
println(y.count())    #Action of RDD
println(z.count())    #Action of RDD
```

It only will read the input file twice now as an action is used along
with the transformation.

**Example 4:** Files read once

```
x = sc.textFile(...)    #creation of RDD
y = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
z = y.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
println(z.count())    #Action of RDD
```

**Example 5:** Files read twice

```
x = sc.textFile(...)    #creation of RDD
y = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
z = y.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
println(y.count())    #Action of RDD
println(z.count())    #Action of RDD
```

Since action are used on two different RDD now so it will read it twice.

**Example 6:** Files read once

```
x = sc.textFile(...)    #creation of RDD
y = x.map(...).cache()    #Transformation of RDD
z = y.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
println(y.count())    #Action of RDD
println(z.count())    #Action of RDD
```

Even now two different action are used only once RDD will be executed and stored into memory. Now the second operation occurs on the Cached RDD.

Edit : Additional Information

So the question arises **What to cache and what not to cache?**
Ans: The RDD which you will be using again and again need to be cached.
**Example 7:**

```
x = sc.textFile(...)    #creation of RDD
y = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
z = x.map(...)    #Transformation of RDD
```

So in this case as we are using `x` again and again.So it is advised to cache `x`.As it will not have to read `x` again and again from source.So if you are working on huge amount of data this will save a lot of time for you.

Suppose you start to make all RDD as cache in memory/disk with/without serialization. If for doing any task if Spark has less memory then it will start to remove the old RDD using LRU (Last Recently Used) policy.And whenever the removed RDD is used again it will do all the steps from source to reach till that RDD transformation.

Comment: So, basically, you can have as many transformations on an RDD, but not more than once actions.

Comment: Transformation will be of no use, unless an action is present for that transformation.

Comment: I mean intermediate RDDs. You can have as many as you want. Only the one on which you perform action needs to be cached.

Comment: The RDD which you will be using again and again need to be cached. Suppose >>>val d = c.map(...) >>> val e = c.map(...). So for this case you can keep c in cache. As it will not have to read c again and again from source.So if you are working on huge amount of data this will save a lot of time for you.

Comment: To add more onto it. Suppose you start to make all RDD as cache in memory/disk with/without serialization. If for doing any task if Spark has less memory then it will start to remove the old RDD using LRU (Last Recently Used) policy.

Comment: @imagin I suggest that your answer with your last comment as it is a useful information. (not everyone reads all the comments on an answer)

Comment: Great answer! Very good examples. `first` will only trigger processing of the first partition. (Unless it's empty.) You could mention this or use `count` instead as an action. Another thing I would add is that it may be faster to re-read the file than to cache it. The only way to decide whether to cache in general is to benchmark the specific code. (As a rule of thumb I agree with your suggestion!)